# GPT Partitioning help!

Tags: hard-drive, gpt

I have a GPT partitioned portable HDD which is not being detected by Windows XP and a non working CD Drive.Can I download and use Ubuntu to boot from and access the data? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Yes, that might work. Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've written you can still boot XP, so two options.

Use the Wubi install to install Ubuntu onto your Windows drive:
http://wubi-installer.org/

Or if your computer can boot from USB then you can make an Ubuntu Live USB install:
http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP does not support GPT drives, but Vista and newer do. You could download an Ubuntu live CD from another computer and burn it to a disc, or possibly download Ubuntu using the Windows installer. The Windows installer for Ubuntu lets you install it just like any other program and remove it quickly from Programs and Features (Add/Remove Programs in Windows XP).

Answer (score 0):

Download a Linux Live CD. Ubuntu will boot off the disk and not affect your drive. I am certain that it supports GPT enabled drives. It should not be a problem to mount, althought it may depend on XP's filesystem.